# Call method helper with link data parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, parameters

I have a series of dynamic links on my view that render like this:

```
<a href="" class="downloadPreset" data-itemid="ddb311d802494a0da355fed6e193db90">Course Image <strong>(600x384)</strong></a>
```

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public class CantoDownloadPreset
{   
    public static FileResult DownloadPreset(string preset)
    {            
       ... 
       
    }
}
```

how can I call the helper **DownloadPreset** method and send **data-itemid** parameter.

Comment: Did my answer help you? You need more information? Please comment on my answer and I will glade to update it. If it helps you, please mark it as correct it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`CantoDownloadPreset` should be a controller in a named file `CantoDownloadPresetController.cs` inside `Controllers` Folder.

Then if you need to do a GET, inherit Controller and remove `static`:

```
public class CantoDownloadPresetController : Controller
    public FileResult DownloadPreset(string preset)
    {            
       ... 
       
    }
```

But take consideration if you want to return a FileResult and where. This question implies a lot of research about how MVC Web Controller works and you should be more in focus. But anyway, the link should be then (only for GET of course):

> /method/action/value

then:

```
/CantoDownloadPreset/DownloadPreset/?preset=value
```